# Compare two files for common and single Numbers

Tags: c, file, file-io

I want to compare two files(a.txt,b.txt) with unknown size , to find the common and single numbers that are inside them , then write them to single and commons others files(commons.txt,single.txt). I think the logic for the bellow code is right , but for some reason both the common.txt and single.txt hasn't the right values.

```
 while (fscanf(a, "%d", &num1) != EOF)
{
    int found = 0;
    while (fscanf(b, "%d", &num2) != EOF)
    {
        if (num1 == num2)
        {
            fprintf(commons, "%d\n", num1);
            found = 1;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (found == 0)
        fprintf(single, "%d\n", num1);

}
```

Comment: You have a flaw in your conditions... What happens if [the `fscanf` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) fails to parse the input from the file? It's not an error leading to it returning `EOF`.

Comment: Are you sure an `O(n^2)` algorithm with I/O is a sane approach?

Comment: @user3121023 thank you it works , if u want post it as an answer

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have in previous lines ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is very inefficient, but should work as a brute force first approach. There are a few details to fix:

- `fscanf()` returns `EOF` only at end of file, you should test if the return value if != 1 to avoid infinite loops and undefined behavior in case of invalid input.
- you must rewind `b` after reading each number from `a`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *a = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    FILE *b = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    FILE *commons = fopen("commons.txt", "w");
    FILE *single = fopen("single.txt", "w");
    int num1, num2;

    if (a && b && commons && single) {
        while (fscanf(a, "%d", &num1) == 1) {
            int found = 0;
            rewind(b);
            while (fscanf(b, "%d", &num2) == 1) {
                if (num1 == num2) {
                    fprintf(commons, "%d\n", num1);
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found == 0)
                fprintf(single, "%d\n", num1);
        }
        fclose(a);
        fclose(b);
        fclose(commons);
        fclose(single);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that numbers present multiple times in `a.txt` will be duplicated in `commons.txt` and numbers present only in `b.txt` will not be present at all in `single.txt`. This might not be the intended behavior. A complete problem description would specify the behavior more precisely and might even hint that the output files should be sorted.

The above implementation has a time complexity of **O(Na * Nb)**. If file `b.txt` is large, it will be very slow. You can reduce the complexity to **O(Na + Nb)** using hash tables if the data can be expected to fit in memory, otherwise an external sort can be used at a cost of **O(Na * Log(Na)) + O(Nb * Log(Nb))** to produce files that can be processed sequentially in parallel.